# Flutter SharedPreferences not recording values but value is set

Tags: flutter

```
SharedPreferences prefs;
Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

Above is how it is initialized

```
prefs.setString('emailPrefs1', email).then((bool success) {
          print('${prefs.getString('emailPrefs1')}');
});
```

Value is set successfully after this

```
    _getPrefs() async {
      prefs = await _prefs;
      String emailPrefs1 = prefs.getString('emailPrefs1');

      if (emailPrefs1 != null) {
        setState(() {
          emailController.text = emailPrefs1;
        });
      }
      print(emailPrefs1);
    }
```

But it returns null after initializing this activity in init state.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getPrefs();
  }
```

I am using shared_preferences: ^0.5.6 version.

Comment: How do you know if it is set successfully? You should print('Email set successfully? $success'). And what does your function _prefs do?

Comment: For me, it looks like you want to set 'emailPrefs1' before you have retrieved the shared preference object.

Comment: Email is set. It prints the email too. But after logging out getString doesn't recieve anything

Comment: look I answered you with some code. What exactly you mean by after logging out? After you closed the application?

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure your 'emailPref' is set, this should work:

```
  class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  TextEditingController _emailController;
  SharedPreferences _prefs;

  Future<SharedPreferences> _getPrefs() async{
    return await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    _emailController = TextEditingController();
    _getPrefs().then((prefs){
      _prefs = prefs; //If you need your SharedPreference Object later on
      _emailController.text = prefs.getString('emailPrefs1');
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(child: Text(_emailController.text))
    );
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _emailController.dispose();
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

How is the private `_prefs` being initialized? You can either share more of your code or just pull the value from what you definitely saved to.

```
  void getPrefs() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance(); // this is what you saved to
    
    String emailPrefs1 = prefs.getString('emailPrefs1');
    print(emailPrefs1);

    if (emailPrefs1 != null) {
      setState(() {
      emailController.text = emailPrefs1;
      });
    }
  }
```

You can also print the value straight from the instance when you do save to confirm a successful save.

```
prefs.setString('emailPrefs1', email).then((bool success) {
 print('${prefs.getString('emailPrefs1')}');
});
```

Comment: Added more code. It is still not working.

Comment: I copied all your code and set an email with a button push and it works fine and is restored after app restart. Are you sure initState is firing when you expect it to?